# Upgrading CPU in laptop

Tags: laptop, cpu, upgrade

My wife would like a laptop, and I'm looking at an HP G6, specifically, a [g6t-2000](http://www.shopping.hp.com/en_US/home-office/-/products/Laptops/HP-Pavilion/A4G32AV;pgid=c7twGfjc0ptSRpIq7ZUcoGXQ0000Xn0psD_s;sid=Cg9NtGx0HyxXoT11Q8fnPLR7ANTAH1hoz1oDaIrRANTAHwxyjI5OYt_P?HP-Pavilion-g6t-2000-Notebook-PC). She says she only wants it for storing photos and so forth, but the techie in me would like to ensure it doesn't become obsolete in a few years (unlike a custom built desktop).

I was customizing the laptop and saw that the base CPU is either 2nd generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2370M Processor (2.4 GHz) or a 2nd generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M Processor (2.3 GHz, 3MB L3 Cache). The max CPU is a 3rd generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3612QM (2.1 GHz, 6MB L3 Cache).

The i3-2350M and i3-2370M are Sandy Bridge (32nm) processors.
The i7-3612QM is an Ivy Bridge (22nm) processor.

What is there hardware or software wise that would preclude me from upgrading the CPU to a better  Ivy Bridge CPU, say, for example, a [3820QM](http://ark.intel.com/products/64889)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick glance at the [3612QM and 3820QM comparison table](http://ark.intel.com/compare/67356,64889) shows that the faster CPU has higher TDP (i.e. draws more power and produces more heat) - so the first two obvious potential hardware issues could be inadequate VRM and cooling system. The model series are also different (36xx vs 38xx) so the CPUIDs are going to be different as well. So there's a chance that 3820QM would require a BIOS update as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would most likely void your warranty and as processor replacement is a delicate procedure that might damage your computer for good. Those issues aside, as long as the processor is compatible with your laptop there shouldn't be too many issues with replacing it.